# Подсчет слов, букв в файле

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Задача такая: подсчитать количество переменных в файле. Т.е. открыть файл и пройтись по строкам в поисках объявления переменных.
пример:

```
    int a,b,c;
    double t;
    char p[20];
```

На выходе должно получиться 5.

Не получается пройти по строке. Код моей попытки ниже:
ищу 'int' в строке, а дальше как пройти по ней не понимаю.
мысль такая, что после нахождения строки с int, double и т.д. подсчитать
количество запятых до точки с запятой, либо если 1 переменная, то
если есть пробел и точка с запятой без запятых между, вооот

```
    char str[3] = "int";
    char y=',';
    while (1)
    {
    estr = fgets (buf,sizeof(buf),file_in);
    yes = strstr (buf,str);
    if(yes !=NULL)
      {
        for(i=0; estr!="\0";i++)
          {
           if(estr[i]== y)
            {
              countPer++;
             }
      }
    printf("%d",countPer);
      }         
        if (estr == NULL)
         {
           if ( feof (file_in) != 0)
         {  
          break;
         }
          else
         {
        break;
        }
        }
        }
        if ( fclose (file_in) == EOF) {printf ("ошибка\n");}
      else printf ("выполнено\n");
```

Comment: Написано на эльфийском, редактировать сложно, ушел спать...

Comment: а почему ищешь `y` а не запятые? И почему от начала строки? Ф-ция ведь возвращает указатель на первое вхождение искомой строки

Comment: "..а почему ищешь y а не запятые?..", ну-с, y=',' выше. В остальном, профан в си

Comment: такое чувство, что приближается время зачетов и экзаменов... уж слишком много подобных вопросов стало.

Comment: верно, остальное сделал, а вот это встало и все тут :(

Comment: Напишите функцию `int get_lexem(FILE *f)`, которая будет читать посимвольно файл и анализировать символы и их последовательности. Пробелы, запятые, скобки и т.п. являются разделителями. Тип разделителя, отличного от пробела, табуляции, новой строки можете тоже возвращать. Последовательность из цифр -- число. Последовательность, начинающуюся с буквы, запоминайте и сравнивайте со списком ключевых слов (операторов и описателей типов). Если очередная такая последовательность не является ключевым словом, то это переменная. Вот их число и считайте.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется нашел в чем у тебя ошибка: в цикле, где ищешь запятые в строке у тебя условие estr != "\0". Сдесь нужно исправить на estr [i] != '\0'. Тобишь сравнивать не строки, а символы в строке.